# How to get a bash prompt in a ssh tunnel with rsa keys?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, shell

After setting client and server with the public keys and allowing PubKeyAuthentication yes, I issue the following command and get a shell that waits indefinitely.

```
mad@amd:~> ssh -T mad@myserver.com
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:01:19 UTC 2012 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

If I type a semicolon, the shell breaks with an error message of syntax error on bash line 2 and the ssh connection drops...

In /var/log/auth.log I see a session opened and no error.

Giving more vvv to the ssh command does not alter the last lines of output nor the behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh`'s `-T` argument causes ssh to not allocate a pseudo-tty, so I'm pretty sure this is the expected behavior. If you want a normal bash prompt—one that behaves normally and doesn't exit like that—omit the `-T`.